# Minified React error #31 when Trying to Use Dash to output a Table in Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to play around with the Dash package in python and I've installed the package and Im just going through their tutorial under the table section.

I'm on the quickstart code found here:
https://dash.plot.ly/datatable

I'm trying to get my table to run but for some reason i keep getting a Minified React error #31 which seems like a Java problem but I cant seem to find any documentation on how to correct this error for a Python/Dash application.

This is my coded version with a different table

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html



df = pd.read_pickle('Results.pkl')


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df2.columns],
    data=df2.to_dict('records'),
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This is my dataframe that I put in dict form for pasting purposes:

```
<class 'dict'>: {'mean_fit_time': {0: 115.53560814857482}, 'std_fit_time': {0: 47.21664776556822}, 'mean_score_time': {0: 1.3890795230865478}, 'std_score_time': {0: 0.15752593751044894}, 'param_learning_rate': {0: 0.08}, 'params': {0: {'learning_rate': 0.08}}, 'split0_test_score': {0: -1.3992662262625548}, 'split1_test_score': {0: -4.582587924346081}, 'split2_test_score': {0: -22.58409221231087}, 'split3_test_score': {0: -12.096604664094432}, 'split4_test_score': {0: -1.0950951211893296}, 'mean_test_score': {0: -8.351529229640652}, 'std_test_score': {0: 8.145994776165953}, 'rank_test_score': {0: 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from your dataframe. The dictionary you're building it from is not formatted properly. Here is the problem specifically:

`'params': {0: {'learning_rate': 0.08}},`

I changed that to:

`'params': {0: 0.08},`

and the table loaded properly.